# Quickest way to get distinct lists using linq/lambdas

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a `List<Dictionary<String, String>> dictionaries`.  Each dictionary will contain the following keys - `WAP`, `SystemCode` and `SubSystemCode`.  A `System` belongs to a `WAP`, and a `Subsystem` belongs to a `System`.  An example of the data you might see is this:

```
WAP | System | Subsystem
-------------------------  
01  | 01     | 01
01  | 02     | 02
02  | 01     | 01
02  | 01     | 02
02  | 03     | 02
03  | 02     | 01
```

I essentially want to get the following:

- **A distinct list of all WAP codes.**

  I think that `var waps = dictionaries.Select(d => d["WAP"]).Distinct();` should work for this.
- **A distinct list of all System codes for each WAP code.**

  The following should work:

  ```
  var dictionaryGroups = dictionaries.GroupBy(d => d["WAP"]);

  foreach (var dictionaryGroup in dictionaryGroups )
  {
     var wapNo = dictionaryGroup.Key;
     var systemCodes = dictionaryGroup.Select(d => d["SystemCode"]).Distinct();
     ...
  }
  ```
- **A distinct list of all Subsystem codes for each System code for each WAP code.**

  Unsure about this one.

Can someone help me out with the last one? And feel free to let me know if there is a better way to do the first two as well.

Comment: so you want: for each combination of WAP/System, give me each Subsystem? Do you want the WAP/System as part of the result?

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful as I need those values to search on.

Comment: Anonymous types implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` automagically, so if you do `GroupBy(d=>new{WAP = d["WAP"], SystemCode = d["SystemCode"]})` the last one should be analogous to the second one.

Comment: I offset the downvote :) its a valid question and example code was provided.

Comment: It's one of the better formatted questions I've seen, and you clearly showed what you needed, where you got to, and that you had actually tried and failed. Upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// linq expression
var dist = from d in dictionaries
           group d by new { WAP = d["WAP"], System = d["System"] } into g
           select g.FirstOrDefault();

//lambdas
var dist = dictionaries
              .GroupBy(d => new { WAP = d["WAP"], System = d["System"] })
              .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: That would actually be the solution for the second step, not the third as the select means if only pulls the first one out of the group, therefore missing all the ones with different subsystems.  But you led me to the final solution - `dictionaries.GroupBy(d => new { WAP = d["WAP"], System = d["SystemCode"], Subsystem = d["SubSystemCode"] }).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())`

Comment: touche. glad I could help anyhow

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following linq query in the [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and the end result should contain the answers for all three questions.

See whether this is what you want.  I used nested GroupBy Linq operator.

To make the sample query simple, I just used a flat array to represent the data shown above. You should be able to tweak the sample query below to apply to the actual dictionaries object.

```
var dictionaries = new [] {
    new { WAP = "1", System = "1", Subsystem = "1"},
    new { WAP = "1", System = "2", Subsystem = "2"},
    new { WAP = "2", System = "1", Subsystem = "1"},
    new { WAP = "2", System = "1", Subsystem = "2"},
    new { WAP = "2", System = "3", Subsystem = "2"},
    new { WAP = "3", System = "2", Subsystem = "1"}
};

var query = 
    from d in dictionaries
    group d by d.WAP into wapGroup 
    select new { 
        WAP = wapGroup.Key,
        SystemGroup = 
            from s in wapGroup
            group s by s.System into systemGroup
            select new {
                System = systemGroup.Key,
                SubsystemGroup = 
                    from s in systemGroup
                    group s by s.Subsystem into subsystemGroup
                    select  new {
                        SubSystem = subsystemGroup.Key
                    }
            }
    };

query.Dump();
```

The result in LINQPad is shown below:

[image]